# which version of log4j2 does apache storm 1.2.2 uses?

Tags: logging, log4j, version, log4j2, apache-storm

As we know storm 1.2.2 release version uses log4j2 for logging. I want to know that which version of log4j2 is being used in here. As i want to modify worker.xml file so that i can delete older logs using the configuration below

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    <Delete basePath="${sys:storm.home}/logs/" maxDepth="1">
      <IfFileName glob="app*.log" />
      <IfLastModified age="" />
    </Delete>
</DefaultRolloverStrategy>
```

Which only works for log4j2 2.5 version or above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.2.2/pom.xml#L250

It's 2.8.2. Storm is a regular Maven project, so you can also find this out by checking out the source and running `mvn dependency:tree`